# How to fix "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id" in ActionChains of Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am pretty new to Python programming.I have been trying to automate a webportal from 2 days using Python and selenium. During this automation, i have to hover and click more than two items. 
Below is my code:

```
hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(Reports_all).click().move_to_element(Reports_production).click().move_to_element(Reports_production_file).click()
hover.perform()
```

`Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id}))` code giving me the below error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: it means that the previous function in your chain returned `None` try doing them in parts and see which one returns nothing

Comment: How can you hover once and click twice ? How would you do it manually ?

Comment: given the last line of the traceback, I'd say that one of `Reports_all`, `Reports_production` or `Reports_production_file` is `None`.

Comment: Add the code that identifies the three elements that are you hovering and clicking. Also, you shouldn't attempt to do all three of these in one line. Separate them out where you hover/click in each attempt. It will make it easier to read and easier to debug.